# Command Prompt Opens and Closes When Running Python Script

Tags: python, command-line

I just recently installed Python and when I write a simple script such as;

```
print 'Hello, world!'
input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

- I save the script to my Desktop as a .Py
- I Run the Script and the Command Prompt opens and closes and repeats, until I go into task manager and kill the process to make it stop opening and closing.

Any ideas on what's going on here and how to fix the issue?

Comment: Most likely you're running the script with *Python3*, and the 1st line generates an error (and the interpreter and its *cmd* window closes before you have the chance to see it). Change it to: `print('Hello, world!')` and try again.

Comment: What is your default application to open .py files, are you running it from command prompt?

Comment: @CristiFati It does not output any type of error. It just opens and Closes repeatedly.

Comment: @Zannith It defaults to using windows powershell.

Comment: @Blake ah, its probably not running it through python. open a command prompt and type `python pathToFile/yourFile.py` (Also make the change CristiFati suggested or it will give you an error). Also if you are wanting to run `.py` files by default i suggest making python your default for opening files with `.py` extension

Comment: @Zannith That Worked! Is there a way to make it so that I do not have to type python Path/Filename everytime. And So that I can just open the file that I saved as a .py?

Comment: @Blake yes by making the python executable your default application for opening files with .py extensions. If you are just getting into python however I would suggest getting an IDE. Then you will have syntax highlighting and you can just run it from within that environment

Comment: You can wrap it in a batch file: c:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\python.exe C:\automation\CompareHoldings\openguiformarketvalues.py

Comment: How do you run the python script? Are you using the command line? Or are you double clicking its icon on the desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue (if you are using Python3) is that the first line `print 'Hello, world!'` should be `print('Hello, world!')`

As far as running it, it needs to be run using python. so in command prompt or powershell you will need to run the command like `python pathToFile/yourFile.py`

Or you can make python your default application for running files with `.py` extensions.

What I would suggest is downloading one of the many free IDE's for python if you are looking at learning the language

Comment: @SuperStew very true, clarified in answer. I assume if OP is just starting into python they would be using python 3, but thank you for pointing that out

Comment: @Zannith Hi, Sorry for taking so long to mark this as correct answer. But thanks for your time!